# compass-rails within a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to make a rails engine use the sprite generation capabilities of compass.
I added `compass-rails` to the main app's Gemfile (outside the `assets` group).

In the engine's CSS file I do:

```
@import "my-engine/icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

Alas, the app looks for images at the wrong dir

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No files were found in the load path matching "my-engine/icons/*.png". Your current load paths are: /home/dan/work/main-project/app/assets/images
  (in /home/dan/work/my-engine/app/assets/stylesheets/my-engine/sources.css.scss)):
```

How and where should I configure compass to look in the right path?

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check:

1. The compass plugin looks in the app/assets/images folder for content.
2. Files need to have a PNG extension only.

## Update for comments

If you would like to save the images elsewhere in your application, for example 'public/sprites', you can specify the follow config setting in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.compass.generated_images_dir = 'public/sprites'
```

Furthermore, since the new sprite file is being saved in 'public/sprites/icons-xxx.png', you will need to add the output path to the assets path in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('public', 'sprites')
```

Comment: 1. yeah I was hoping it would look at the assets/images of the engine, not the main app. 2. checked!

Comment: Updated answer with alternative location for your sprites. Upvote or tick if this proves to be helpful :)

Comment: thanks for the update but I meant that my source images are in the engine, not the main app. Also, AFAIK the main app is not supposed to know about the engine's idiosyncrasies.